# Error: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs (Docker)

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs

I am receiving the error: `No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs` in a Docker container when trying to run `hadoop fs -ls`

I am volume mounting my local machine's `/etc/hadoop/conf` directory so the configurations are the same.  I have no problems running the `hadoop fs -ls` command on my local machine.

Similar answers are not helpful because they do not address the host/docker issue.

I am running on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix.  The issue was because the directories:

`/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce`
`/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs`
`/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce`
`/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn` were not present in the Docker container.  Once I volume mounted those directories into my container, it worked perfectly.